# Android live_wallpaper feature filtering for Galaxy S and other phones

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, galaxy

About 6 months ago I've put a live wallpaper on the market, only to discover it did not appear on the market for Galaxy S.

The GalaxyS seemed to report to the market that it does not support live wallpapers, while it does.

I ended up removing the `uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"` from the AndroidManifest.xml

Since then I get many low ratings and frustrated emails from users which have phones that do not support live wallpapers, but downloaded the application (MyTouch Slide, Aria and others).

Can anyone confirm that this problem have been solved? 
I.e. If I know set the AndroidManifest to declare it uses the live_wallpaper feature, will it appear to all the phones that actually support it, including the Galaxy S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, Galaxy S did not show my live wallpaper ("Slider Live Wallpaper") in the Android Market here in Germany. This seems to be fixed now.

Comment: So - if I setup the filter back to "uses feature live_wallpaper" - it will show up for users of GalaxyS?